# Efficiently query lots of Firestore documents and limit amount of results?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

More of a general question, how would one go about using `Swift` to query through hundreds or even thousands of documents stored in `Firestore` and limit the amount of results to some amount (let's say 100).

From the Firebase docs, I found the `.limit(some_number)` function that you can tack on to the end of a `.where` query. The issue with this is that if some_number is 100, then it appears to only search 100 documents, not keep searching until it gets 100 results. If only 60 out of 100 of those documents match what you were searching for, then you get 60 instead of it continuing to search until you get to 100.

Am I missing something?

For context, in my case I have a query that looks like this:

```
let db = Firestore.firestore().collection("users")

db.whereField(gameKey, isEqualTo: gameValue)
  .whereField(rank, isEqualTo: rankValue)
  .whereField(mic, isEqualTo: micValue)
  .whereField(platform, isEqualTo: platformValue)
  .limit(5)
  .getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
    for document in (snapshot?.documents)! {
      print("Found a player that plays this game")
    }
  }
```

gameValue is a bool (if player plays the game then its true)

rankValue is a string (ex: "Gold 2")

mic is a bool (if player has a mic then its true)

platform is a string (ex: "PS4")

**Edit 1**: added code for context

Comment: That's not the way it's supposed to work.  Without seeing your query and having an understanding of the data you're trying to query, it's not really possible to say what's going on here.

Comment: @DougStevenson ive updated my question with my query and what data im trying to query

Answer (score 1):

So this isn't an answer specifically but more of a proof that includes error checking - it may help you catch where the error is in your code.

I created a FireStore with 100 users with the following format

```
uid_0
    gameValue: "1" //or "0"
    micValue: "1"
    platformValue: "1"
    rankValue: "1"
```

50 of the users had their gameValue set to "0", the other 50 set to "1"

I then ran the following piece of code 10 times.

```
func readGameData() {
    let usersColl = self.db.collection("users")
    let query = usersColl
        .whereField("gameValue", isEqualTo: "1")
        .whereField("rankValue", isEqualTo: "1")
        .whereField("micValue", isEqualTo: "1")
        .whereField("platformValue", isEqualTo: "1")
        .limit(to: 25)

    query.getDocuments { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
            return
        }
        if let snap = querySnapshot {
            if snap.count > 0 {
                for document in snap.documents {
                    let key = document.documentID
                    print("player: \(key) plays this game")
                }
            } else {
                print("no players play this game")
            }
        } else {
            print("no data returned")
        }
    }
}
```

It responded with a list of the first 25 players that matched the shown query criteria. I then adjusted the .limit parameter to different values from 1 to 25 to 100 and it returned 1 result, then 25 results, then 50 results. Keeping in mind that there were exactly 50 players with a gameValue of 1.

So that may indicate the error lies elsewhere in the code or perhaps there is an inconsistency in how the FireStore properties are structured.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have misunderstood how Firestore queries work. The limit you can specify is the maximum number of documents the query may **return**, it is not the maximum number of documents it may search.

If you use `limit(100)` on a query, the query returns the first 100 documents that match the query. If there are fewer than 100 documents that match the query, it will return all the matches.

Comment: So my case in particular has a collection called "users" with user documents in it. All the user documents have games that they play in them (my app find teammates for people). If I query by using .where(playsGame, isEqualTo: true) then I get back 5 of my 10 test documents meaning that there are 5 users in the collection that play that particular game. When I add .limit(5) on the end of that query, I only get 3 documents back. Coincidentally, of the first 5 user documents in the collection only 3 play that game. Hence why it seems to me that it only searches the limit amount of documents.

Comment: That's not how queries are supposed to work, and I've also never seen that happen in practice. It's of course always possible there's a bug in the SDK or server-side somewhere. Can you reproduce the problem with fewer fields and fewer documents, so that we can try to reproduce it locally?

Comment: I'll make a smaller demo and see if I can reproduce it. Probably won't get to it until tomorrow though unfortunately. Will post another comment when if I can replicate it. And I understand that's not how they're supposed to work which is why I'm going crazy wondering why this isn't working. It's just one of those days haha